# C# get string replacing NULLs with line break

Tags: c#, string, unicode, arrays

I have a byte array that contains list of unicode strings. Each string is terminated with `0x00 0x00`. `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` works, but it returns me one concatenated string. I would like to have it with line breaks.

One possible solution is to replace the `0x00 0x00` sequence with line break and then convert byte array to string with mentioned above function, but I don't see how can I do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any reason not to convert it to a string first and then use normal string replacement?

```
var text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(binary).Replace("\u0000", "\r\n");
```

EDIT: As noted, you may want to use `Environment.NewLine` to get the line separator of the current system. It depends on your context.

Comment: OP probably assumed the `null` character is lost.

Comment: what about `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: vidstige: I think this is be better.

Comment: @vidstige: It depends on what's required. *Sometimes* you want "the line separator of your current system" - other times you want a particular line separator because that's what your protocol requires. There's no indication of which situation the OP is in.

Comment: For my situation Environment.NewLine is OK. Thanks.